# How can I show the field setting options like "Style Settings", "Rewrite Results" in Views

Tags: 7, views

I created a view and added some fields, I saw others can configure field options like "Style settings" and "Rewrite Results", but in my "Configure Field:" window, I don't have these options, only several blank rectangles. See below image,
[image]

Is there any settings I missed or any new modules I didn't installed?

Comment: Could be a Javascript/jQuery problem, just a guess. Do you have jQuery Update installed?

Comment: I just upgraded my drupal core from 7.4 to 7.50. And jQuery upgraded to version 1.10. Those options still can't be shown up:-(

Comment: Is this happening to a specific view or every view on the site. Try creating another view with different content type and fields. Also try downgrading jQuery version.

Comment: Views work best - from my experience - with jQuery 1.7. Try to set the version for admin pages to that using jqueryUpdate. And if that doesn't work, next question would be what your admin theme is (probably seven judging from your screenshot).

Comment: I configured  jQuery version to 1.7 using jQuery Update module. And also tried re-creating new views, and also tried another theme - Bartik..clean all caches. but those settings are still not there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I realized it's a web browser issue. I was using Google Chrome and the options are hidden by some "injected stylesheet", see following screenshot,
[image]

And I change to use IE, it works fine (jQuery version 1.10 is fine also), all these options are showing properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a jQuery issue. Downgrade to 1.5 for administrative pages only (admin/config/development/jquery_update). Greater versions break views and other admin areas - not sure why though

Comment: Thanks Argyro, I downgrade to 1.5 and still not work. I tried drupal core version 7.36 and 7.50...not work:-(... Any other possible reason?